# Initialize Spring Bean as late as possible

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a follofing situation int "super-context.xml":

```
<bean id="conf" class="ee.Conf"/>

<bean id="service" class="ee.Serivce">
  <property name="conf" ref="conf">
</bean>
```

Now I want to use this "super-context.xml" in various different projects. Say "sub-context.xml" has:

```
<import resource="super-context.xml"/>

<bean id="subConf1" class="ee.SubConf">
   <property name="confloc" value="classpath:ee/customconf1.sss" />
</bean>

<bean id="subConf2" class="ee.SubConf">
   <property name="confloc" value="classpath:ee/customconf2.sss" />
</bean>

...

<bean id="subConfn" class="ee.SubConf">
   <property name="confloc" value="classpath:ee/customconfn.sss" />
</bean>
```

ee.Conf is something as follows:

```
public class Conf ... {
    ...
    public void addSubConf(Resource res) {
       //configuration resolving from res
    }
    ...
}
```

ee.SubConf is something as follows:

```
public class SubConf ... {
    ...
    @Autowired
    ee.Conf superConf;
    ...
    public void setConfloc(Resource res) {
       superConf.addSubConf(res);
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem aries on context load. Beans are initialized in following order (due to ordering in context file): conf, service, subConf1, subConf2, ... subConfn

But service bean actually depends on all the subConf beans (although this can't be deducted from the context definition itself). It loads OK when import in "sub-context.xml" is added after subConf bean definitions.

Reason behind this is implementing modularity. Is it possible to force a bean to load as late as possible ("service" bean in the example) or make beans of certain type load as soon as possible ("subConf" beans in the example), since fixed ordering of beans in "sub-context.xml" partly kills the wished modularity

Or is theree a more pure way to achieve this type of modularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you are approaching the problem in a wrong way. The `SubConf` shouldn't have a dependency on the `Conf` to start with. Simply inject the collection of `SubConf` objects in your `Conf` object.

```
public class Conf {

    @Autowired
    private List<SubConf> subconfs;
}
```

That way you eliminate the need for the `SubConf` to call the `Conf` class and this will remove your circular dependency.

See the [Spring reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) for more information on autowiring.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem exactly. I was not aware that you could autowire all beans of some type in the given way

Answer (score 1):

You can use `depends-on`

```
<bean id="beanOne" class="foo.Bar" depends-on="beanTwo" />
```

Comment: @Lance Java I considered it but my problem is that "super-context.xml" is not aware of the custom "sub-context.xml" that will be added to it in various projects. Therefore there isn't any sure beans to "depend-on"